# Getting "ErrorException" while implementing Laravel 4 class Auth::login()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a web application where users can signup and post questions. Everything went alright until I was trying developing a function where users will be automatically logged in upon registration. I used Auth::login() class just like I used to do with Laravel 3 but I'm getting the following error:

```
"ErrorException Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of       Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of Member given"
```

while I implemented the class with registered user's creds. I guess Laravel 4 has changed the way the class would work in it's previous version but I can't figure it out in their documentation as well as searching here in StackExchange before I post this question.

Here is the codes in my UserController

```
public function postCreate() {

    $validator = Member::validate(Input::all());

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $user = Member::create(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
        ));

        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::route('home')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!');
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('register')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused about the default User.php model provided with Laravel 4. I usually would create a User model based on the users table in my database while I would work in laravel 3. But this time in laravel 4 I had to change my user table name to members so that I can use my own model Member.php. Is it alright if I remove the codes in default User model or should I place my own functions at the top keeping the existing codes provided by Laravel?

P.S. I'm relativeley new with the MVC concept and started learning with tutorials on Laravel 3 and that's why I'm finding it hard to get myself used to with Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement `UserInterface` to fix the error. In addition, if you need password reminder functionality, you have to implement `RemindableInterface` as well.

In your `Member` class add the following lines:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Member extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

Comment: Alright I guess I'm beginning to understand this a bit. I have just updated the $protected table method to my table which is members. It works now. But I'd like to understand how and where to implement those methods like protected $hidden = array('password');

P.S: Although it's working now I'm facing another weird issue. After users logout they shouldn't have access to the admin page clicking back in the browser. But after logging out I'm still going back to the admin page simply clicking back arrow button in the browser. How do I take care of that?

Comment: You need to use Auth filter. `Route::filter()`. more info: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Answer (score 1):

As the Exception says, your Member-Model needs to implement `UserInterface` in order to use the `Auth` helper:

```
class Member extends Eloquent implements UserInterface
```

Here a quote from [Code Bright by Dayle Rees](https://leanpub.com/codebright):

> Our User model implements both UserInterface and RemindableInterface. What are these for?
>   Well the UserInterface let’s Laravel know that the model contains all methods needed for it to
>   authenticate with Laravel’s own authentication system. The RemindableInterface allows Laravel
>   to retrieve the users email address or other contact information to allow for the functionality of
>   sending password reminder emails.